# Starting couchdb without root

Tags: linux, couchdb

I want to run a non-system-wide couchdb instance (as a local, unprivileged user). But couchdb needs to be able to read /etc/couchdb/*.ini, which are `-rwxrwx--- 1 couchdb couchdb`, even if I tell it to reset the configuration chain with `-n`.

How do I convince couchdb it doesn't need to read those files?

Answer (score 0):

If this program is not prepared to skipping these files then you can

1. either adapt the access rights of the files (think of default ACLs for their parent directory if new files will be created)
2. run it in a chroot / lxc environment

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the location of the `*.ini` files through the `-couch_ini` command line flag or the `ERL_FLAGS` environmental variable.

Also, make sure to configure a database directory as well, that's accessible to your user! For example I was able to launch it with the following command:

`couchdb -couch_ini /home/isti/tmp/couch/test.ini`

Where the contents of the `test.ini` file were:

```
[admins]
admin = password

[couchdb]
database_dir = /home/isti/tmp/couch/dbdir
```